# Finding Mod_Rewrite Rules on Cent OS Server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos

I am having a bit of a problem finding some mod_rewrite details. I am taking over from another PHP web developer. I am used to Ubuntu servers and I am migrating a few sites onto a new Ubuntu server. The old server is CentOS. The old developer used mod_rewrite rules and as they're rather specific, I'm trying to track them down on the server but cannot find them for the life of me. I know it's a bit of a needle in a haystack question but does anyone know where they could be? I've looked within the individual sites var/www/vhost/SITENAME/ config. Not in there. I've looked in the etc/httpd config files too and they're not there. They are also not stored on the file server within htaccess. Thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 0):

Usually the VirtualHost config files are under `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

What you could do is `grep -ri rewriterule /etc/httpd/conf*|more` to see if the RewriteRules are defined anywhere within the configuration directories.

You should also check `grep -i include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to see if configurations are included from somewhere besides the default `Include conf.d/*.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still can't find it though? I wonder if he's used aliases? @Ketola

Comment: That's a possibility depending on what is being done. You could grep for `AliasMatch` as well to check. Assuming you have root access you could also try to `locate .htaccess` to find all the htaccess files on the server. Just in case you've missed one. While you're at it, check httpd.conf to make sure that htaccess is still configured at it's default value (`AccessFileName .htaccess`).

Comment: thanks very much for your response. I've done this and unfortunately no luck. guess i've just gotta keep searching. inheriting work without documentation is always a challenge. thanks